# laravel 5 how to pass data to a name route from a view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

generally my aim is to pass a data that will serve as identifier in an href attribute..

my route is somethign like this.

```
Route::bind('video', function($slug){
return DB::table('videos')
            ->select('slug')
            ->where('slug', $slug)
            ->first();
});

$router->get('/vid/{video}', ['as' => 'video_page', 'uses' => 'HomeController@vid']);
```

my controllers method is this.

```
 public function vid($video){
    $slug = $video->slug;

    return $slug;
 }
```

and in my view.

```
 <a href="{{ route('video_page') }}">{{ $vid->title }}</a>
```

my question is how to pass data that would look like this,

```
 <a href="/vid/my-slug">my-title</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a second parameter to the route() function. Like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('video_page', ['slug' => $vid->slug]) }}">{{ $vid->title }}</a>
```

Comment: exactly what i needed, by the way i change the code to this ['video' => $vid->slug] to match my datas, thank a lot

Comment: Nice! Can you please mark the answer as correct, with a green check mark?

Comment: yep i will, it ask more time before i can mark it as an answer, but i will when its available, thanks again